# super prefix in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, super

So total noob to Swift/programming so excuse the seemingly obvious question;
Could someone explain to me the functionality of the super prefix?
Does it allow for the override to retain the functionality of the parent class?
The tutorial I am working on tells me its used to let the parent class know when the child class is called? Not sure i fully understand this.
Thanks in advance for the help!

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var pictures = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
        let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
        
        for item in items {
            if item.hasPrefix("nssl") {
                pictures.append(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Share link to this tutorial.

Comment: “Does it allow for the override to retain the functionality of the parent class” ... Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that `UITableViewController` did some stuff in `viewDidLoad` that was necessary for its operation, much like how your view controller does. When you override the inherited method, yours gets called instead of the super class's. Now you have a chance to do your initialization, but you've deprived the super class of the opportunity to do its initialization.

To remedy this, you would call the super implementation yourself. A lot of UIKit view cycle methods (`view(Will|Did)(Load|Layout|Appear)`) don't strictly need to be called, because the super class implementations do nothing, but some do. Omitting them could lead to funky results, hence why it's usually good practice to make a habit out of calling the super class implementations of such methods.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected as much.